# Conformal mapping to distort a square box?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry, conformal-geometry

Assume that I have a (possibly unit) square in some $z$-plane which I want to distort into the $w$-plane through a conformal mapping. My question has two successive parts:

1. If I know the images of (i) the edge points and (ii) circular arcs which are orthogonal to each other, does a conformal map such as the one shown below exist? If so, how could I find it?
2. Is it possible to find a **unique** conformal map similar to the one below if I only have the edgepoints in the $z$-plane and their images in the $w$-plane?

[image]